# Previewing a Crystal Report Form in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am working on a Crystal Report Form (.RPT). I am trying to align some values on the Form, but because the space on the form is limited and the names of formula are quite large, it's not possible to fix this by merely looking at the names on the Form. To check the alignment, I have to Run the application and go through several steps to reach the Form and then verify if things are coming properly.

Is there anyway to preview the Form without having to Run the App and go through several steps.

Comment: aren't you using the preview feature in Crystal Reports?

Comment: Where is this preview feature?

Comment: Ok, I found it. But the problem is, the way it shows output there isn't quite the same as it appears after running the App.

Comment: Could I suggest bigger monitor? :) Oh, and can't you save report with data in your application - then you can align fields afterwards (in standalone Crystal Reports designer app of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--->>> To check the alignment

It's not very clear what you want to achieve.

Still if you have many text fields over form and want to aligh, or set same size. Just multi select -> right click on one item -> in pop up you will see options align and size. This will apply all selected items.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did find a review button. The pain is, the names of formula are so long that they overlap onto each other. That's why it's difficult to see if I am doing the alignment properly.